# Using One String in a Dictionary For an If-Statement (Python 3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, variables, dictionary

```
diction1 = {"Pikachu","Harambe","Potato"}

name = input()
if name == diction1:
    print("Yay")
```

^Except it doesn't work.

High schooler here, studying dictionaries. Just wanna know how do I get an input from one variable to match one of the strings in my dictionary to comply with my if-statement.

Sorry, by the way, if this question has been asked already. I'm not too familiar with the terms, so I may have not been able to search the right questions.

Comment: That's a set, not a dictionary. You're currently comparing the input with the whole set rather than checking for membership within the set.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/exYuxo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's not a dictionary but [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). It's also based on hash-tree. You should check it in the following way:

```
if name in diction1:
    # do stuff
```